# Android: Vibrate in accordance with selection checked in Sound Settings > General

Tags: android, notifications, vibration

How can I do that? My current code is shown below:

```
final NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_sys_warning, System.currentTimeMillis());    
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Uri.EMPTY, context, Activity....class).putExtra(...);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, text, contentIntent);
manager.notify(1, notification);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [Notification#DEFAULT_ALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_ALL), as well as `DEFAULT_VIBRATE` below it.  You are not currently indicating that you want the `DEFAULT_VIBRATE` configuration (your current code only selects `DEFAULT_SOUND`.

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

If you want to use the device-default settings for both Sound **and** Vibrate, you can do that using bitwise OR:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Alternatively, you can specify that you want to use *all* the default notification settings:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
```

In addition to that, you also need to make sure that you have the [`VIBRATE` permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#VIBRATE) specified in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```